# How do I fix the issue that causes svn2git to fail with "no associated commit metadata"?

Tags: git, svn2git

I am attempting to convert a remote Subversion repository to git on my local Windows machine. I installed ruby, svn2git, and then created a file called `authors.txt` for converting the associated committers.

When I run the command `svn2git my://repo/url --authors authors.txt`, I get the error:

```
Checking svn:mergeinfo changes since r3: 1 sources, 1 changed
refs/remotes/svn/Production: no associated commit metadata

command failed: git svn fetch
```

I have searched around and I was unable to find any situation that applied directly to my error. Anyone have a clue why this error would pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, but from your question I see you are not using the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to configure it for your layout to get the result you want and expect.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of a SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I'd handle the conversion on the server as I would have on my windows computer, then push the git back to my hosting service, and then pull it down to my computer?

Comment: You can do it on the server or on your Windows computer, doesn't matter. As long as you have the repository files at hand, either directly copied by hand if you have access or via svnrdump or rsvndump e. g. After you created the gut repo, you can do with it what you want. You can just transfer it to your Windows machine, you can clone the repo on the server from the Windows machine, or you can push to anywhere and then clone from there, doesn't really matter much.

Comment: When I attempt to run 'git clone git://annongit.kde.org/kde-ruleset', it intializes the empy GIT repo but then comes back with 'anongit.kde.org[0: 31.216.41.69]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)' Does this mean that the ruleset is no longer available?

Comment: The correct URL is git://anongit.kde.org/kde-ruleset.git and I just cloned from it successfully. But you don't need it, except for examples.

Comment: Tried it again with that ruleset and it seem to have worked out correctly. Appreciate the help!