# SVN2GIT - no associated commit metadata from SVN, skipping

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

I am getting warning "no associated commit metadata from SVN, skipping"

I am using https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git tool. What does the above message mean? I am trying to migrate whole history from svn to git.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what that warning means, but I'd recommend not using that tool.

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

The nirvdrum `svn2git` one you use effectively calls `git-svn` and then does some post-processing to overcome some of the drawbacks of `git-svn`, but it still suffers from quite some of them.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories like yours that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` or the nirvdrum `svn2git` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: I am actually using svn2git.

Comment: Copy-pasting this answer everywhere is really not productive. Especially for this question it is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Reading this statement for the third time in a row using google to find a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662669/577052 https://stackoverflow.com/a/38304001/577052 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184869/577052 https://stackoverflow.com/a/37987245/577052